# Can't seem to save multiple objects in parse (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having some issues with saving multiple related objects into the databrowser.

Here i'm trying to create a relation between friends, so i'm creating an Array of "friendsAdded". Currently I can create a one-way relationship of the user adding a friend.

Such as this:

```
 protected void addfriend(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String kliquitId =(((List<KliquitUser>) userlist).get(position).getObjectId());

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> otheruser = ParseUser.getQuery();
    otheruser.getInBackground(kliquitId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser otheruser, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            user.addUnique("friendsAdded", otheruser);
            user.saveInBackground();

}

    });
```

**So Here's the problem...**

I want to create a "two-way relationship" whenever an add friend happens...

So, I can't seem to add the current parse user to the array of "friend who was added"..

I tried this.but it doesn't work:

```
protected void addfriend(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String kliquitId =(((List<KliquitUser>) userlist).get(position).getObjectId());

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> otheruser = ParseUser.getQuery();
    otheruser.getInBackground(kliquitId, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser otheruser, ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            otheruser.addUnique("friendsAdded", user);
            user.addUnique("friendsAdded", otheruser);
            user.saveInBackground();

}

    });
```

Does anyone have any idea??

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User table is secured by Parse in that you can not modify another User object, you can only modify the currentUser object.  From the Parse docs:

"The ParseUser class is secured by default. Data stored in a ParseUser can only be modified by that user. By default, the data can still be read by any client."

Your line `otheruser.addUnique("friendsAdded", user);` should not be allowed as you are modifying a different User object than the currentUser with this attempt.

I *believe* the correct approach for you would be to use a Relation instead of an Array.  You shoud read up on the Parse docs very thoroughly - a lot of the answers you will seek will be right there in the docs.  Read up on relational data:  https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers

Comment: oh I see, because the developer working on the project before me used an array. and my iOS side is using the same database tables, so if we did change the arrangement there would be some database inconsistencies. So is there a way? or would there be no way for that?

Comment: The only other way I know is that you can use a Cloud Code function to change other users

Answer (score 0):

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < imageArrayList.size(); i++) {
                                pos = i;
                                byte[] image = (getByteArray(imageArrayList.get(i)));
                                final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("abc.jpg", image);
                                final int finalPos = pos;
                                file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        parseFiles.add(file);
                                        if(finalPos == imageArrayList.size()-1)
                                        {
                                            ParseObject imagelist = new ParseObject("Images");
                                            imagelist.put("refrence", form.getObjectId());
                                            imagelist.put("imagesfile", parseFiles);
                                            imagelist.saveEventually();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                            }
```